# Why is Trojan unlocked in Classic mode but not in Story Mode?

Tags: sigma-theory

I unlocked [Trojan](https://sigmatheory.fandom.com/wiki/Trojan) through her story arc and she is now available to recruit, but she is only showing up in Classic mode. She is not available in Story mode.
Is there something I need to do to unlock her in Story mode too?